# SQL connection string is not recognised and throws and exception in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, wpf

CONTEXT: I am writing a WPF app. It works with a SQL Server database in which I put some data, concretely the strings Titulo and Descripcion, the int XP and the string fotoMision. When I click a button the program is supposed to save this data in the database.

PROBLEM: when I click the button it throws me an exception in string connection's line showing that the object is not instanced. If I put these first lines right below the `InitializeComponent();` line the second one doesn't recognise the `miConexion` string. Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

CODE:

```
static string miConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myProgress.Properties.Settings.DatosHabilidades"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection miConexionSql = new SqlConnection(miConexion);

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string consulta = "INSERT INTO datosMisiones (Titulo, Descripcion, XP, fotoMision) VALUES (tituloMision, descripcionMision, xpMision, nuestroIconoMision";

    SqlCommand miSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, miConexionSql);

    miConexionSql.Open();

    miSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", tituloMision);

    miSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    miConexionSql.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please state the *exact error message* you are receiving.

Comment: `InitializeComponent();` does not exist in your code fragment and it is not clear which specific line is throwing the error. But there are many problems with your code and I suggest you start over with a good tutorial that discusses updating a database with parameterized queries.

Comment: "*the object is not instanced*" does that mean you get a NullReferenceException? Where exactly does it occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connections are meant to be short-lived, i.e. you should create one when the button is clicked and then dispose it right after you have executed the query. Using a [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) implicitly disposes the `IDisposable`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string Consulta = "INSERT INTO datosMisiones (Titulo, Descripcion, XP, fotoMision) VALUES (tituloMision, descripcionMision, xpMision, nuestroIconoMision";
    string miConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myProgress.Properties.Settings.DatosHabilidades"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection miConexionSql = new SqlConnection(miConexion))
    using (SqlCommand miSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Consulta, miConexionSql))
    {
        miConexionSql.Open();

        miSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", tituloMision);

        miSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        miConexionSql.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as you say and it still gives me this exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and then it shows again that Connection String's line threw a null value.

Comment: @Clasher: Is "myProgress.Properties.Settings.DatosHabilidades" a key in your `App.config`? Otherwise it should be `string miConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myProgress.Properties.Settings.DatosHabilidades].ConnectionString;` without quotes.

Comment: Ok so I managed to get rid of the that exception following your answer. Thank you! But it now throws me a new exception in the miSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); line, it says the following: the name of the tituloMision column is not valid (and also with the other three columns). That's strange because I don't have any column named as this in my SQL database, so why does this happen?

Comment: @Clasher: `VALUES (tituloMision` ... in the `Consulta` query string should be `VALUES (@Titulo` ... or whatever the name of the parameter is.

Comment: @Clasher: But please ask a new question if you have another issue. I believe your original question has been answered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think it's better for future viewers of this question to see the different errors of my code and correct them. And I'm so sorry to say that with all the changes made, it throws me this in the ExecuteNonQuery() line: "Incorrect syntax near ','.'. Some idea of where does that SqlException come from?

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near..." is a totally different exception than the one mentioned in the original question, isn't it? Stackoverflow is not about to "to see the different errors you code". It's a Q&A site.

Comment: True enough. I'm so sorry. I marked the answer as valid as it solves the original problem. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The format of your connection string for a SQL Server Database should be like so:

```
"Data Source=DNS_or_IP_Address;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword"
```

[Connection Strings and Examples for various databases](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't see that error. I changed it to the Connection String example that Visual Studio gives me (Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=DatosHabilidades;Integrated Security=True) and it still refuse to work.

Answer (score -1):

put connectionstring on form_load event